# iTerm2 Color Coding on Symfony Website

Tags: color-scheme, iterm

I am looking for the color coding for iTerm they used on the screencast on http://symfony.com/. Does anybody know?

I googled and found a lot different color schemes, but they only affect background color, fonts etc. but they do not differ between the type of elements within your terminal window.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the solution for *colorful output* for terminal from *symfony console tool*?

The colorful output formatter is originally supported from symfony console script itself, you might add the parameter `--ansi` to check the result:

```
php app/console --ansi
```